# Bash - flag is not setting for finding evidence of file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I know this has to be something simple, but I'm just not seeing it. We have a file, `SpeakerList.txt`, which contains a series of single lines of a speaker in our database. `new.trs` holds a space-delimited version of the database. I need to verify that we find the speaker in the database, so I'm running a `grep` for lines that start with the speaker name. The following code always results in the `if` statement at the end triggering for every speaker. I've got a similar bit of code that checks for file existence and it works just fine. What am I missing? I know that my `grep` loop is running — I've tried it with debug `echo` lines. I've also tried printing out the `$speakerFound` field and verified that it is indeed blank at the end, even when I have a statement showing that it was marked "found" earlier.

```
for i in `cat SpeakerList.txt`
do 
  speakerFound="" 
  echo "Speaker: $i"
  grep "^$i" ~/work/new.trs | while read line
  do 
    fileName=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 2`
    speakerFound="found"
    break
  done

  if [ "$speakerFound" == "" ]; then
    echo "$i not found in database."
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your `speakerFound` variable in a subshell.  Read [this link](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=178) for more details, but in general:

- When you redirect the `stdin` of a loop in bash, the loop will execute in a subshell.
- Because the loop is a subshell, variable assignments inside the loop will not be visible outside of the loop.

One solution is to use a file on disk to contain the result (write it in the inner loop, and read it back in when you need the result).

Comment: Or move the check into a function and use `return` to set the exit code which you can then check.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP needs more than just a result code...but if that's the case, you don't need to move the check into a function; you can explicitly run the loop inside a subshell (via `(...)`) and just call `exit <returncode>`.

Comment: That indeed did it. I changed the code to create and remove a dummy file for the speaker being found. I guess the other one worked because it was inside a `while` loop looking through the grep output. Thank you.